# Do I have to use the Instagram API?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, feed

I was thinking of retrieving a user's Instagram news feed, however the Instagram API doesn't allow you to do that because some users may be private. However, what if I just used an HTTP connection and logged in as the user then went to the user's 'home' page to get their news feed? I think this would work, but I'm not sure about the legalities behind doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See their [Terms of Use](https://help.instagram.com/478745558852511). Specifically...

> We prohibit crawling, scraping, caching or otherwise accessing any
>   content on the Service via automated means, including but not limited
>   to, user profiles and photos (except as may be the result of standard
>   search engine protocols or technologies used by a search engine with
>   Instagram's express consent).